# $.getJSON is not entering the function and not getting any data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('button').click(function() 
    {
        $.getJSON('http://world.needforspeed.com/SpeedAPI/ws/game/nfsw/server/status?output=json', function(json)
        {
            alert("Entered getJSON");

            $("#output").append("working...");            
            if(json.status.indexOf("success")===0)
            {
                alert("success");
                $.each(json.results, function(i, data) 
                {
                    $("#output").append(data.text);
                });
            }else
            {
                alert("Failed to load url");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The json that is pulled from the url looks like:

```
{"worldServerStatus": {
 "customMessage": "",
 "lastChangedDate":  {
  "date": 31,
  "day": 4,
  "hours": 17,
  "minutes": 48,
  "month": 4,
  "nanos": 0,
  "seconds": 32,
  "time": 1338486512000,
  "timezoneOffset": 0,
  "year": 112
 },
 "localizedMessage": "The servers are currently up and running.",
 "message": "ALL_SYSTEMS_GO",
 "status": "UP"
}}
```

My jquery just refuses to enter the $.getJSON function, the "enetered getJSON" alert doesn't fire.

What is wrong?

Solved. Thank you all :)

Comment: Is your site hosted on the same domain you're trying to retrieve the JSON from?

Comment: no, it is hosted on http://mlp-nfsw.net

Comment: You can't make an AJAX call like that to a different domain than your own.

Comment: http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com/

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Don't say "solved"! Click on the check next to the solution below that  worked (and if none of them is even close, provide your own answer; that's allowed provided you write it as an answer).

Comment: I know, I cant accept answers instantly  ... I just put solved there for now until i can select a solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery.getJSON - Access-Control-Allow-Origin Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396623/jquery-getjson-access-control-allow-origin-issue)

Comment: @Skye I am also facing the same problem. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check the console? You might be suffering from a access-control-origin error

[jQuery.getJSON - Access-Control-Allow-Origin Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396623/jquery-getjson-access-control-allow-origin-issue)

Comment: the fix here is to replace getJSON with a regular jQuery ajax call and set it's dataType to jsonp

Comment: that will only work if the site actually responds with a proper JSONP response; plain JSON won't work.

Comment: The server has to support JSONP as well and `getJSON` will do a "JSONP request" if set up properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can not fetch JSON from another domain unless they support [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) because of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Does the api support [jsonp](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to do this. For cross domain ajax requests the api provider have to use jsonp. What you can do is create a php file for the request. Lets call the file request.php

```
<?php   
/* gets the data from a URL */
function get_data($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}

$query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$url = ('http://world.needforspeed.com/SpeedAPI/ws/game/nfsw/server/status?'.$query);

echo get_data($url);

?>
```

Then in your javascript

```
$.getJSON('http://myserver.com/request.php?output=json', function(json)
```