# Why is an OPTIONS request sent to the server?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, jquery

I use a simple jQuery.ajax method:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: serviceUrl + '/GetAgentsGroupNameById',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { id: agentsGroupId },
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            agentsGroupName = data["d"];
        },
        error: function (request, message) {
            agentsGroupName = '';
        }
    });
```

The 'Get' request is sent and I get a well-formed json response from the server.
The problem is that I see in the developer tools that another request is generated to the same URL, with request method: OPTIONS, with an empty response, and I see an error:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:1004/MobileService.asmx/GetSubscribedAgentsByUserId?userId=27 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

What is this OPTIONS request?
Why does it happen?

P.S. I mentioned that if I delete contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" (and add dataType: json or jsonp), no OPTIONS request is generated, but I don't get a well-formed json as a response (I get kinda xml document)

BTW: the service is asp.net c#:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetAgentsGroupNameById(int id)
```

**PLEASE LET ME KNOW IF YOU NEED ANY FURTHER DETAILS ABOUT THE REQUEST OR THE RESPONSE**

Thanks from advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OPTIONS request is because of the [Cross origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). It is basically the web browser asking the destination server whether it allows cross domain resource sharing.

In short, you cannot make json requests to a different domain than the domain that the page is being served from.

If you are only doing GET requests, you may want to look at [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) which solves this issue. However, it only works with GET requests.

There have been a lot of questions on this, and there is a details answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396623/jquery-getjson-access-control-allow-origin-issue)

Comment: Not sure where that link is supposed to take people though?!

Comment: I only do "GET" request, as you can see, and when I use dataType:'jsonp', I have no errors, but I get an xml document as a response, instead of a json object.

Comment: @DavidMasters Oops, wrong link :p This is the one I intended to use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control.

Comment: btw, the service I use has a response header of "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *", so I'm not sure if the cross origin resource is the problem

Comment: @benams Hmm interesting. Do you get xml back even when you have set contentType to application/json & dataType to jsonp?

Comment: yeah.. here is what i get back: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Sports</string>.
Maybe something wrong with the webservice itself?

Comment: @DavidMasters I can see now in the developer tools that the response has an header of "Content Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" although I set the contentType to be application/json

Comment: Are you talking about the OPTIONS request or your GET request? The browser will make the OPTIONS request before the GET by itself ignoring the headers you've specified...

Comment: when I set dataType: 'jsonp' I see no OPTIONS request in the developer tools. I attach a link to a printscreen of the developer tools with the request and response's details: http://i50.tinypic.com/w9h11j.png

Comment: @DavidMasters [forgot to tag you in my last comment...]

Comment: To be honest, I don't know why you are getting xml back. I haven't actually used jsonp myself because I need POST requests. Maybe ask another question titled 'Why do I get an XML response from a JSONP request'. But I think I've answered your original question regarding why OPTIONS requests occur.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it. THANK YOU!
and one more thing: you told that you use POST requests, you can get json response like that??
@DavidMasters

Comment: I have modified my web service to add the required CORS headers which means my post requests work. So when I make an ajax request the browser makes an OPTION request first...

Answer (score -1):

Try switching your $.ajax 'Type' to use the POST verb rather than GET.

Comment: I don't believe that would make a difference.