# Get request works with curl but not with javascript

Tags: json, firefox, curl, get

I am trying to access information through a GET request.  My javascript code is getting a successful response, but with an empty JSON array.  I am trying to debug using curl and Firefox.  Here is where it gets strange.

Here is a successful request through the Firefox:

```
 http://api.example.com/v4/layers/2178198/features?token=...&filter=time%253E1384889546
```

This returns a bunch of data.  This also works in my javascript code.

Now I do exactly the same request with a slightly different resource:

```
http://api.example.com/v4/layers/2178199/features?token=...&filter=time%253E1384889546
```

And I get a success, but the JSON array returned is empty.  I do this exact same request with curl (from the same machine):

```
curl  http://api.example.com/v4/layers/2178199/features?token=...&filter=time%253E1384889546
```

and I get a JSON array full of data.

So I know that I can GET data from the server with javascript and Firefox.  And I know that this resource is valid, because I can access it through CURL.  Why oh why do I get no data when accessing through the browser?  I am very confused.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?  Is it possible you requested the /2178199 resource previously and the empty result is cached?

Comment: I just cleared the cache and tried it, still with no luck.  I even used a different browser that I haven't tried this on yet, and still no luck.

Comment: What affect does your token and filter querystring params have on the request?  Is it possible that the token you are passing via the browser is in conflict with session state?

Comment: @DavidFleeman, you are on to something.  It seems to be a combination of two problems.  One is on the server end: the data that should be there is not there.  The other is that I didn't quote my cURL request, so the shell was corrupting the filter string and thus returning the wrong data.

Comment: Who is the API provider you're pulling data from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to transform from curl command to ajax request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243595/how-to-transform-from-curl-command-to-ajax-request)