# angular.js $http.post not working in phone

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, http, ionic-framework

I have a big problém,
I made a small application ionic , angularjs that works without error,
when I add `$http.get()` call to receive a JSON file
  the browser displays the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load ..... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

```js
         $http.get("http://elite-schedule.net/api/leaguedata")
                    .success(function(data) {
 
                            deferred.resolve(data);
                    

                    })  .error(function() {
                        console.log("Error while making HTTP call.");
                                                 deferred.reject();

                     });
```

I add the extension `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *`
and the application returns  run
but my problem in my phone (android) it does not display anything
I think we should allow this appeal $http.get

please, who knows display console.log () in the phone , to know the source of the error or who has already this error

thank you a lot

Comment: Im confused about the error message. Do you wanna make a request to `http://localhost:8100` or `http://elite-schedule.net`?

Comment: Use Jsonp insted of json.check the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396623/jquery-getjson-access-control-allow-origin-issue

Comment: Since you are developing a hybrid app, you may eventually move to cordova. Take a look at whitelisting : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: but my problem that's work normal in browser and not in phone
I think ,if there is an error it's not work anywhere !!!

Answer (score 0):

This kind of question occurs every day. Firstly read about CORS: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Then if you can change server configuration, then do it(if it's ok for your security policy, of course). If not, do jsonp request. If it's not available either.. find another API.