# How to extract data from json array with jquery and append it in html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to extract data from Json array and append it with html table with jquery
like

- idly 5
- dosa 20

This is how my browser **console prints what my server returned**

```
    {hotelMitem: Array(5)}
    hotelMitem: Array(5)
    0: {hname: "idly", iprice: "5"}
    1: {hname: "dosa", iprice: "20"}
    2: {hname: "dosa", iprice: "20"}
    3: {hname: "dosa", iprice: "20"}
    4: {hname: "dosa", iprice: "20"}
    length: 5
    __proto__: Array(0)
    __proto__: Object
```

[But when i try to iterate & print with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548661/print-json-values-into-html)

```
    var _jsonString = "";
                for(var key in data){
                    _jsonString +="key "+key+" value "+data[key]+ '</br>';
                }
    $("#datatable").append(_jsonString)
```

**HTML OUTPUT what i get**

```
key hotelMitem value [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Comment: `for(var key in data.hotelMitem)` maybe?

Comment: Why do you want to use jQuery rather than just JSON.parse(data)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through `data.hotelMitem`, not `data` itself. As the keys are static you can just access them directly without the additional inner loop. You then need to build the actual HTML to populate the table with `tr` and `td` elements. You can achieve that using `map()`, like this:

```js
var data = {
  hotelMitem: [{
    hname: "idly",
    iprice: "5"
  }, {
    hname: "dosa",
    iprice: "20"
  }, {
    hname: "dosa",
    iprice: "20"
  }
  // more items...
  ]
};

var html = data.hotelMitem.map(function(obj) {
  return `<tr><td>${obj.hname}</td><td>${obj.iprice}</td></tr>`;
});
$("#datatable").append(html)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="datatable"></table>
```

Comment: this works thank you for making it clear to me @Rory McCrossan