# JQuery $.getJSON from PHP file_get_contents on steamcommunity JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, steam, steam-web-api

I try to use `http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/XXXXXXXXXX/753/6` to fetch JSON items.

I can't put the url in my `$.getJson` because there is a `CORS « Access-Control-Allow-Origin »` error.
How can i bypass that if i don't want to allow CORS
I read somewhere that it's possible to use PHP `file_get_contents` to redirect the json file.

Steamcommunity doesn't work with JSONP

```
var exercice = {

modules: {}
};

exercice.modules.ajax = (function () {

return {

    recupererJson: function () {
         initial= $.getJSON('proxy.php',function(data){
        })
            initial.done(function(donnes){
                var i = 0;

                $.each(donnes.descriptions,function(key,value){
                        $('tbody').append("<tr>");
                        $('tbody').append("<td>"+value.name+"</td>");
                        $('tbody').append("<td><img src=http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/"+value.icon_url+" alt ="+value.name+"/></td>");
                        $('tbody').append("</tr>");


                    });
                    });
    },
    init: function () {
        exercice.modules.ajax.recupererJson();
    }
}})();

$(document).ready(function () {
exercice.modules.ajax.init();
});
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery.getJSON - Access-Control-Allow-Origin Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396623/jquery-getjson-access-control-allow-origin-issue)

Comment: JSONP is not allowed on this website, so i didn't find my answer in this post either :/

Comment: If the website doesn't allow JSONP, and you have no control over that, you'll have to execute the call in PHP, because any reasonable browser will prevent you from doing it in the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `php.ini` has `allow_url_fopen=1` (http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php), which should be by default, then you can make such a php file:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/76561198033103987/753/6');
```

or

```
<?php readfile('http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/76561198033103987/753/6');
```

Otherwise if it is disabled and you cannot access php.ini, but you have CURL extension enabled, then you can do so:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, 'http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/76561198033103987/753/6');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
echo curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php

**EDIT:** Looking at your code it seems to me that there is only one issue here:

```
initial= $.getJSON('proxy.php',function(data){
```

should be

```
initial= $.getJSON('http://example.com/proxy.php',function(data){
```

You should use full URLs.

**EDIT2:** I tried this code and it worked fine for me.

`http://127.0.0.1/test.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var exercice = {
            modules: {}
        };

        exercice.modules.ajax = (function () {

        return {

            recupererJson: function () {
                 initial= $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1/proxy.php',function(data){
                })
                    initial.done(function(donnes){
                        var i = 0;

                        $.each(donnes.descriptions,function(key,value){
                                $('tbody').append("<tr>");
                                $('tbody').append("<td>"+value.name+"</td>");
                                $('tbody').append("<td><img src=http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/"+value.icon_url+" alt ="+value.name+"/></td>");
                                $('tbody').append("</tr>");


                            });
                            });
            },
            init: function () {
                exercice.modules.ajax.recupererJson();
            }
        }})();

        $(document).ready(function () {
            exercice.modules.ajax.init();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

`http://127.0.0.1/proxy.php`:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
readfile('http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/76561198033103987/753/6');
```

I added `Content-Type` header so that the proxy.php would form a more browser-friendly. Also `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header should prevent CORS from blocking the ajax request if you open the test.html using file URI `file:///C:/www/test.html`.

Comment: It always say No element found i will put some code

Comment: So it works for me but only on Google Chrome, Firefox keep telling me CORS problem

Comment: @Kryze, I tried it on both chrome and firefox, and firefox didn't throw any errors. The only way I get CORS error is when I open test.html directly using a file URI `file:///C:/www/test.html`. But it works fine when I open it through my local webserver via url `http://127.0.0.1/test.html`.

Comment: @Kryze, I may have found a solution for your issue. Try adding `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` into proxy.php. You can see that in the updated code.