# jQuery.getJSON and an URL as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have a jQuery code

```
        $.getJSON(
        "http://my.website.com/cors",
        {
                url: "https://www.someREST.com:8888/rest/v1",
                last: self.last(),
                first: self.first(),
                address: self.address()
        },
            function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data.entry));
       });
```

but when I call that `getJSON` an URL parameter has added backslashes to each slash and `encodeURIComponent()` it makes even worse.

Any tips on that?

Comment: Try using `decodeURIComponent`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar that is adding backslashes too

Comment: Adding backslashes or escaping quotation marks?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by what you have going on there, i think you are specifying too many URLS, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Try reformating like so

```
$.getJSON("https://www.someREST.com:8888/rest/v1",
    {
        last: self.last(),
        first: self.first(),
        address: self.address()
    },
        function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data.entry));
   });
```

I'm not a CORS guy so I don't fully understand where you were going originally.

Comment: It must to go over `http://my.website.com/cors`as proxy for IE9 - other way is not going to work due to CORS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396623/jquery-getjson-access-control-allow-origin-issue

Comment: There are other factors which doesn't allow to use direct `getJSON` from IE9 like request must be targeted to the same scheme as the hosting page (in this case HTTP vs HTTPS) that is why it must to be called via "proxy" app.