# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' with jQuery getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cors

I know there is no shortage of `CORS` questions on SO but none could help me in this circumstances:

I'd like to get JSON data from localhost backend using this jQuery snippet:

```
var SERVER_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8080";

$.getJSON(SERVER_URL,function(result){
    console.log("result is", result);
  $.each(result, function(i, field){
    $("div").append(field + " ");
      });
    });
```

The snippet is loaded to `index.html` which is run on `http://localhost:3000/index.html` using this simple node static-file server:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname)).listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server running on 3000...');
});
```

But in Chrome console I get:

```
Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8080/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I had the same issue in Firefox.

How can I fix this?

Comment: see https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static/issues/153 how to pass access-control-allow-oringin header

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10872804/2954326

Comment: @Lars-OlofKreim will you please elaborate your answer? I get error while trying to use that suggestion.

Comment: what is the error you get? :)

Comment: @Lars-OlofKreim `ReferenceError: nodeStatic is not defined`

Comment: hmm could you try the way how the set the header here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static#serve-all-files-as-downloads This is the packed you use, isn't it?

Comment: @Lars-OlofKreim Yes, that's the package. But not sure how to modify it for CORS.

Answer (score 0):

install `cors` package

```
npm install cors
```

and use like this

```
var cors = require('cors');

const corsOptions = {
  methods: "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",  // use to manage api cross origin error
  origin: '*'
}
```

**OR**

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Run This Command it will open new chrome and run your code here

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

Comment: Well, as you see, I don't use express.

Comment: i add two ways to use `cors`

Comment: I tried your first solution and still get the CORS error.

Comment: i add another solution try it @Babr

Comment: Thank god I'm not on Windows. :)

Comment: what happen bro any problem ? @Babr

Comment: I tried your second solution and receive `Cannot GET /index.html`. I guess you need to add code for static file.

Answer (score 0):

You should set header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` at your server.
The way you should do is depend with your server side language.

Ex: PHP

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
?>
```

Comment: it's clearly about node.js not php

Comment: I don't use php sir.